# Flutter: CupertinoPicker to trigger functions inside the List

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to trigger functions inside the List with the CupertinoPicker.

```
var _aa = [
      () {
        print('hello1!');
      },
      () {
        print('hello2!');
      },
      () {
        print('hello!3');
      },
    ];
```

Trying to execute `_aa`'s functions. However, when I try to use it inside the CupertinoPicker, I get `Avoid using unnecessary statements.` statement.

```
   CupertinoPicker(
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
                         print(i);
                         _aa[i]; <--- error statement
                        },
                        itemExtent: 32.0,
                        children: List.generate(
                          _aa.length,
                          (i) {
                            print(i);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Function> _aa = [
      () {
        print('hello1!');
      },
      () {
        print('hello2!');
      },
      () {
        print('hello!3');
      },
    ];
```

You forgot to add .call(), like this:

```
onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
                         print(i);
                         _aa[i].call();
                        },
```